# When will EmEditor Javascript be updated from ES5.1?

Tags: macros, ecmascript-5, emeditor

EmEditor macro's are still based on JavaScript 5.1, which is (in 2022) ten years old and seven versions behind.

Many modern methods and functions are missing and it is hard to find good documentation (other than the official [ECMA-262 5.1 edition, June 2011](https://262.ecma-international.org/5.1/) archive).

I am wasting a lot of time trying to find out what works and what doesn't work in EmEditor macro's.

Will EmEditor JavaScript ever be updated?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Why don't you ask the developers? [contact form](https://www.emeditor.com/support/#contact)

Comment: @Yutaka: Thank you very much for updating to modern JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EmEditor `22.0.905 or later` supports **modern JavaScript** using the **V8 JavaScript engine**. Please select **Customize** on the **Macros** menu, select the **Option** page of **Customize Macros** dialog box, and set the **Use V8 as JavaScript engine** option.